# Does to_utc_timestamp take into account daylight saving?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I'm trying to convert EST datetime to UTC in a Hive query, but can't see daylight saving taken into account. Do you know how to account for daylight saving in Hive?

For example:
`TO_UTC_TIMESTAMP('2014-12-31 00:00:00', 'EST')` gives `2014-12-31 05:00:00` i.e. 5 hour difference
`TO_UTC_TIMESTAMP('2014-06-30 00:00:00', 'EST')` gives `2014-06-30 05:00:00`, also 5 hour difference

I'm expecting the June query to give a 4 hour difference.

In June the East Coast observes EDT (Eastern Daylight Savings Time), but Hive doesn't understand EDT at all:
`TO_UTC_TIMESTAMP('2014-12-31 00:00:00', 'EDT')` gives `2014-12-31 00:00:00` i.e. no difference

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Ilmari

(Running Hadoop 1.0.3 on AWS Elastic MapReduce)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an open ticket from the Hive project that address this issue.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-12194

See 2nd comment:

> Ben Breakstone added a comment - 16/Oct/15 16:54
>   It's worth noting the daylight saving time version of US three-letter codes like "PDT" are not included in /lib/zi/ for the Oracle JDK. New identifiers like "PST8PDT" appear to work as expected.
>   See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/alertfurtherinfo-139131.html

Perhaps as Ben Breakstone suggests new identifiers will work?